# How to run a single test or single TestCase with django-nose?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, nosetests, django-nose

With Django's normal test runner, you can drill down to run tests in a specific app, a specific subclass of TestCase, or a specific test within a specific subclass of TestCase.

E.g.:

```
./manage.py test myapp.MyTestCase.test_something
```

However, django-nose doesn't appear to support anything beyond testing a specific app.  How do I replicate the last two behaviors?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Nose [supports](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#selecting-tests) the following syntax (note `:` between test script name and test class name):

```
./manage.py test myapp.tests.test_script:MyTestCase.test_method
```

Comment: It beast me why they wouldn't have used the Django standard of using a period... seems pretty backwards to me.

Answer (score 7):

The correct answer is ./manage.py test myapp/tests/test_script:MyTestCase.test_method.

Using dots in the relative path did not work for me, but slashes did.

Comment: Does not work for me: `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`